# ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory truncates name causing file name collision

Tags: c#, zip

I need to unzip (N) files from a local directory.  I am using .NET 4.5 and the using System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory  for extraction. My problem is this renames the files upon extraction.  Example both of these files will extract to Scouting_20160603 directory.  So when I get to the second extraction there are name collisions.

cheers
bob

WPFPotatoScouting_20160603.zip

WPFRotationScouting_20160603.zip

Answer (score 0):

Turned out inside each file was a directory named Scouting_20160603.  Why it unzipped to that name and not the file name is still puzzling me.  But I have this answer.